# issue installing react native expo with npm install -g expo-cli

Tags: react-native, android-studio, npm, expo

> I was able to install and run react-native
>
> but when I tried to install react native expo I got some errors

this is my Expo installation **npm install -g expo-cli**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\admin>npm uninstall -g expo-cli
up to date in 0.043s

C:\Users\admin>npm install -g expo-cli
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more fetching binaries from AWS, smaller package size
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.

> @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.10.0 preinstall C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\traveling-fastlane-linux
> node platform.js

Does not seem like WSL enabled on this machine. Download a Linux distro from the Windows Store, run it at least onceand then make sure to run in an admin powershell:
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo-cli -> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo -> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js

> iltorb@2.4.4 install C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\iltorb
> node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild

info looking for cached prebuild @ C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_prebuilds\95b49f-iltorb-v2.4.4-node-v72-win32-x64.tar.gz
info found cached prebuild
info unpacking @ C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_prebuilds\95b49f-iltorb-v2.4.4-node-v72-win32-x64.tar.gz
info unpack resolved to C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\iltorb\build\bindings\iltorb.node
info unpack required C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\iltorb\build\bindings\iltorb.node successfully
info install Successfully installed iltorb binary!

> libxmljs@0.19.7 install C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\libxmljs
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --loglevel http

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.19.7/node-v72-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.19.7/node-v72-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.19.7/node-v72-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for libxmljs@0.19.7 and node@12.13.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.19.7/node-v72-win32-x64.tar.gz
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:225:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:302:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:314:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--loglevel=http" "--module=C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\libxmljs\\build\\Release\\xmljs.node" "--module_name=xmljs" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\libxmljs\\build\\Release" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\libxmljs
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --loglevel=http --module=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release\xmljs.node --module_name=xmljs --module_path=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--loglevel" "http"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\libxmljs
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --loglevel=http --module=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release\xmljs.node --module_name=xmljs --module_path=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-darwin-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.10.0 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\traveling-fastlane-darwin):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.10.0: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-win32-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-sunos-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! libxmljs@0.19.7 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --loglevel http`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.19.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-15T12_28_16_679Z-debug.log

C:\Users\admin>npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).hapi.im

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\admin\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.12.0 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm


C:\Users\admin>
```

This is what I get when I try to create a expo app

```
C:\test>expo init expoprojext
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js'
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: []
}

C:\test>
```

can you help me with this ##########################################################################################################

Comment: Why are you calling:  npm uninstall -g expo-cli ??? you want to install it not uninstall it: npm **install** -g expo-cli

Comment: @yesIamFaded  install expo (sorry i corrected it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Today I tried to update my expo-cli and got the same error. So I installed an older version again. You can try this, it worked for me.

```
npm i -g expo-cli@3.5.0
```

EDIT: 
Now there is a [bug report](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1237) at Expo-CLI Github page & someone suggested to run `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` and then install the latest version of Expo. This npm package installs Visual C++ Build Tools and Python 2.7. If you want the latest version of Expo, you can try this.

Comment: It seems that later version of expo-cli is having some issues. In my case it was failing with error of `ELIFECYCLE`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there could be quite a few issues here and I don't think a simple answer would suffice..

would need to know what environment that you are running your command from

That being said, you could use advice from this GitHub issue thread and simple try and use npx

```
npx expo init {my-project}
```

https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/590

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command instead.

```
yarn global add expo-cli
```

Answer (score 1):

Same happened for me and in addition to uninstalling expo-cli through command line I had to manually **uninstall the .expo folder** under c/users and any expo and expo-cli related file under C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm. Only then when installing the older version of expo (3.5.0) it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Additional suggestion: Make sure your Node version is up to date.  `nvm use 14` solved my problem.  You can of course check your version with `node --version`.