# Command gets stuck while installing expo-cli

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I am trying to install `expo-cli` on Windows 10 OS for react native through `npm install expo-cli --global` command, but it gets stuck at this line.

[image]

- I've tried clearing `npm` cache and reinstalling `node`.
- I've tried running the command `npm install expo-cli --global` in powershell.
- I've tried installing `expo-cli` through `yarn`, but it gets stuck on an error `There appears to be trouble with your internet connection. Retrying...` ,although I checked and my internet is working fine.

I'm not able to figure out how to resolve it.

Comment: same happening with me in my mac? how did you solve this problem?

Comment: @kdblue I searched for the solution, and for me it got solved by installing the visual-studio-tools and Python 2.0 which has to be installed while installing node js. Here's the link- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58886642/11342806

Answer (score 3):

1. run `npm cache verify`
2. run `npm install expo-cli --global --no-optional`

this worked for me. Also, consider using Powershell instead of cmd

Answer (score 2):

Just wait and make sure the network connectivity is good. It took time for me too. Anything bash, cmd or powershell will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to wrong configuration of your node.

If you used home brew to install node.js, uninstall it and re-install node again using the package installer from the nodejs official website.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with npm and your internet connection, sadly. The expo-cli package is quite large to install so any internet connectivity issues would become clear during the several minutes it may take on the first install. I would suggest trying it again on another internet connection if possible. If you do not think that this is the problem, you can try to build it from source at https://github.com/expo/expo-cli

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked is:

1. Start CMD as administrator
2. Run `npm cache verify`
3. Run `npm install expo-cli --global --no-optional`

Also, verify that you use the correct `node` version.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue! What ultimately worked for me was the following command:

`npm install -g expo-cli --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

For me it took 9 hours to install at Ubuntu through Windows 10 by WSL2. My suggestion is to open the Task Manager to see if is there any usage of CPU, Memory or Disc... The usage was high during all the installation, so if it is high means that the installation is not stuck, but only taking much time.